# Gitlab Group API returns different values depending on the token used

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am querying Gitlab group API using curl. The result I get when I use my PAT token is different than when I use the CI_JOB_TOKEN. The PAT token returns all the groups I have access to but using the CI_JOB_TOKEN returns a weird response. I read the CI_JOB_TOKEN has the same permission as the user running the pipeline.

```
'curl --header "--header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups"'
```

Returns the below response which I have no idea what it is. It is not one of my groups:

```
teur-territoires/france-relance/","visibility":"public","share_with_group_lock":false,"require_two_factor_authentication":false,"two_factor_grace_period":48,"project_creation_level":"developer","auto_devops_enabled":null,"subgroup_creation_level":"maintainer","emails_disabled":null,"mentions_disabled":null,"lfs_enabled":true,"default_branch_protection":2,"avatar_url":"https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/group/avatar/16026247/france-relance-vert.png","request_access_enabled":true,"full_name":" France Relance","full_path":"france-relance","created_at":"2022-02-05T20:55:13.007Z","parent_id":null,"ldap_cn":null,"ldap_access":null}]
```

While running with my PAT token, it returns the right results and in the right format:

```
curl --silent --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $MY_PAT_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups"

[
  {
    "id": xxxxxx,
    "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/groups/txxxxest",
    "name": "xxxx",
    "path": "xxxxx",
    "description": "",
    "visibility": "private",
    "share_with_group_lock": false,
    "require_two_factor_authentication": false,
    "two_factor_grace_period": 48,
    "project_creation_level": "developer",
    "auto_devops_enabled": null,
    "subgroup_creation_level": "maintainer",
    "emails_disabled": null,
    "mentions_disabled": null,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "default_branch_protection": 2,
    "avatar_url": null,
    "request_access_enabled": true,
    "full_name": "xxxx",
    "full_path": "xxxxx",
    "created_at": "2023-01-29T08:41:38.696Z",
    "parent_id": null,
    "ldap_cn": null,
    "ldap_access": null,
    "marked_for_deletion_on": null
  },
  {
    "id": xxxxxx,
    "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/groups/xxxx",
    "name": "xxx",
    "path": "xxx",
    "description": "",
    "visibility": "private",
    "share_with_group_lock": false,
    "require_two_factor_authentication": false,
    "two_factor_grace_period": 48,
    "project_creation_level": "developer",
    "auto_devops_enabled": null,
    "subgroup_creation_level": "maintainer",
    "emails_disabled": null,
    "mentions_disabled": null,
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "default_branch_protection": 2,
    "avatar_url": null,
    "request_access_enabled": true,
    "full_name": "xxxxxn",
    "full_path": "xxxxxx",
    "created_at": "2023-01-29T13:58:49.800Z",
    "parent_id": null,
    "ldap_cn": null,
    "ldap_access": null
  }
```

I am not sure why it is exhibiting this behaviour. I dont want to manage a PAT token if I can use the CI_JOB_TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your CI script

```
'curl --header "--header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups"'
```

it should be:

```
'curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups"'
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that - I fixed that but same output